# Как собрать сборку Chromium (CEF) с видео кодеками?

Tags: c#, c++, delphi, opensource, chromium

подскажите пожалуйста, как собрать сборку Chromium с видео кодекам? интересует воспроизведение видео в программе где будет использоваться Chromium. нужен именно способ собрать сборку с поддержкой этих кодеков. как мне известно, их вырезали из него из-за патентов.

сам проект на Delphi

**Спасибо за внимание!**

Comment: Хочется собирать именно самому? Взять [готовые сборки](https://chromium.woolyss.com/#windows) не вариант?

Comment: если есть готовые сборки с нужными кодекам, то линки пожалуйста)) если не сложно. собирать его не очень хочется,  ресурсоёмкий это процесс. думал, что готовых вариантов нету.

Comment: В моём предыдущем сообщении есть соответствующий линк.

Comment: совсем ослеп уже) только как их использовать? там готовый хром, у него свои названия dll'ок...

http://vfl.ru/fotos/2db7e1c423678525.html

библиотеки libcef.dll нет, может просто сделать замену какую? но не всё же так просто)

Comment: Действительно, dll не те. Тогда, придётся собирать самому: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45404590/6219657

Comment: спасибо)) будем пилить.